Seeking Help to Prove Surjectivity of a Function on $\mathbb{R}^2$
I have established the injectivity of the function given by the mapping $(x, y) \mapsto (x + f(y), y + f(x))$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable ($C^1$) function satisfying $|f'(x)| < \lambda$ for a fixed $\lambda < 1$. Now, I aim to demonstrate the surjectivity of this function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The challenge is to prove that for every point $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x + f(y) = a$ and $y + f(x) = b$.
I am seeking insights or methodologies to approach the surjectivity aspect of this proof, especially utilizing the properties of $f$ to ensure that the map covers every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now I think it's hopefully can be proven by the intermediate value theorem.

Now I think I have finished the proof using IVT, and if anyone is interested to my solution, I will post it no early than tomorrow.

I am curious how you showed that the map is injective. Surjectivity seemed intuitive to me here but injectivity is a surprise!

Edit This was an answer to a previous version of the question, and is no longer relevant.

Let's denote this map by $\varphi := (x,y) \mapsto (x+f(y), y+f(x))$.

First, we will show that the diagonal $\Delta := \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is contained in the image of $\varphi$.
When restricted to the diagonal, we have $\varphi|_\Delta = (x,x) \mapsto (x+f(x), x+f(x))$, so it suffices to show that $x \mapsto x + f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is surjective. This follows from the intermediate value theorem: let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. We have $y - \lambda + f(y - \lambda) < y$ and $y + \lambda + f(y+\lambda) > y$, so there is some $x \in (y-\lambda, y+\lambda)$ such that $x + f(x) = y$.

Now, let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be arbitrary. We know that $(a,a)$ is in the image of $\varphi$, so pick some $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\varphi(x_0, y_0) = (a,a)$.
Now consider the curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$\gamma(t) = (x_0 + f(y_0) - f(y_0 + t), y_0 + t).$$
We note that the $x$-coordinate of the curve $\varphi \circ \gamma$ is constant with value $a$:
$$x_0 + f(y_0) - f(y_0 + t) + f(y_0 + t) = x_0 + f(y_0) = a.$$
So, to show that $(a,b)$ lies in the image of $\varphi$, it suffices to prove that the $y$-coordinate of $\varphi \circ \gamma$, i.e.
$$t \mapsto y_0 + t + f(x_0 + f(y_0) - f(y_0 + t)) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$$ is surjective. Equivalently (ignoring the constant term), we want to show that
$$g := t \mapsto t + f(x_0 + f(y_0) - f(y_0 + t)) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
is surjective. This follows from the intermediate value theorem: let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. We have
$$g(y - \lambda) = y - \lambda + f(\textit{something}) < y$$
and
$$g(y + \lambda) = y + \lambda + f(\textit{something}) > y,$$
so there is some $x \in (y-\lambda, y+\lambda)$ such that $g(x) = y$. $\square$

This argument only used that $f$ is continuous -- we didn't use the full strength of the assumption that $f$ is $C^1$. Did your proof of injectivity need that $f$ is $C^1$?

It seems that the injectivity is  ot  necessarily true. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x%2B0.99+sin%28+x%5E2%29 for the first component restricted to the diagonal.

Could you explain how you could use IVT by only assuming continuity of f?
Moreover the example doesn't work since its derivative is not bounded on R, by Chain Rule.

I've edited my answer to spell out the second IVT proof. You can see that neither of proofs use the fact that $f$ is differentiable; the IVT applies to all continuous functions.

Jens' counterexample does work -- you did not specify that the derivative of $f$ should be bounded.

Sorry for miss-printing the problem! I have corrected it now. What I want is the derivative is bounded.

Our main goal is to solve this system:
$$x_0 = x + f(y)$$ and $$y_0 = y + f(x)$$
To simplify the system , we isolate $y$ from the second equation to get $y = y_0 - f(x)$ and substitute it back into the first to derive a new function in terms of $x$ alone:
$$g(x) = x + f(y_0 - f(x)) - x_0.$$
This definition allows us to focus on analyzing the zeros of $g(x)$, significantly simplifying our approach to proving the bijection.
The injectivity of the mapping is demonstrated by showing that $g(x)$ is strictly increasing. We compute the derivative of $g(x)$:
$$g'(x) = 1 - f'(y_0 - f(x)) \cdot f'(x).$$
Given that $|f'(x)| < \lambda < 1$, it guarantees $g'(x)$ is positive because the term $f'(y_0 - f(x)) \cdot f'(x)$ is less than $\lambda^2$, hence less than 1. Therefore, $g(x)$ is strictly increasing, establishing the injectivity of our function.
We want to use IVT to prove g has a zero on $R$, the intuition is that when x is sufficient positive or negative large, $f(y_0 - f(x))$ will be dominated by $x$. To make this idea precise, we use MVT and estimate that $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq\lambda|x| $, which gives
$$|f(x)|\leq\lambda|x|+|f(0)|$$
Now we start to examine the limit behaviors of $g$:
When $x$ is negative, we have:
$$g(x)\leq x+|f(y_0-f(x))|-x_0 \leq x+\lambda|y_0-f(x)|+const\leq\ x+\lambda^2|x|+const=(1-\lambda^2)x+const$$
Therefore
$ \lim_{x\to-\infty} g(x)=-\infty $
Similarly we can show
$ \lim_{x\to+\infty} g(x)=+\infty $
Therefore we can apply IVT to $g$ to conclude that $g$ has a zero in $R$. This concludes the system is consistent and has unique solution for every given $(x_0,y_0)$, which means the bivariate function is bijective.
